# cite an unpublished thesis in latex with \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

Tags: bibliographies, citing, thesis, texworks

There is this thesis from 2016, which is not available on the internet and I am trying to cite it. I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext.
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext \cite{XYZ2016}.

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} 
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

and in the .bib file:

```
@article{XYZ2016,
titel={bla bla},
autor={ASD, XYZ},
school={Rostock University},
year={2016}
}
```

but in the text it just shows [?]. Could anyone help me here?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you run `bibtex`?

Comment: @TeXnician indeed! but still does not wokr!

Comment: Well, for article there are missing required fields. Probably bibtex will have warned you. See the wikibook for more information.

Comment: I afraid not. I have over 40 refs and they all work perfectly. This is the only one. I do not understand where the problem is.

Comment: Well, just worked! I still do not know why, but I can keep going. :)

Answer (score 2):

Whatever else you do, you should *under no circumstance whatsoever* be using the `@article` entry type for an unpublished thesis. The `@article` entry type should be used only -- repeat, *only* -- for pieces published in journals. By extension, the `@article` type should also not be used for books, chapters in books, working papers in a working paper series, and anything that belongs in the `@unpublished` entry type.

Since you're using the `ieeetr` bibliography style, you should consider using either the `@mastersthesis` or the `@phdthesis` entry type for the unpublished thesis at hand. Both entry types recognize and process the following fields: `author`, `title` (`@mastersthesis`) or `btitle` (`@phdthesis`), `year`, `month`, `school`, `address`, and `note`.